# QlikSense: "Hide" a hyperlink within a string

Tags: qliksense

I'm aware of how to make a hyperlink in one of my tables, but what I'm hoping to do is have the link a bit more "hidden" and within a string. For example:

[image]

I don't want this entire string to be a hyperlink, *just* the process id value. Is this possible in QlikSense?

EDIT: For clarification, what I'm wanting to do is have my report output have something like "Process Id: 225181 | Task Id: 39487..." but only the process id value of 225181 is the hyperlink.

Comment: You can use subfield( <the openning tag of hyperlink>, 0 ) then concat & then subfield( <the closing tag of hyperlink>, 1 ), something like that. Need more information of how your entire string